# In the movie Terminator 2, why doesn't the T-800 cease to exist when history is changed?

Tags: time-travel, the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day, bootstrap-paradox

In the movie Terminator 2, we find that Sarah and Terminator (Arnold Schwarzenegger) himself helping to destroy the files in the Cyber-something factory + the recovered neural net microprocessor which *will* cause him to be created 40 years in the future (bootstrap paradox here). So when the course of its creation is altered, he immediately should cease to exist. At least when the chip is dropped into the molten steel.

This is a fictional rendition of grandfather paradox, isn't it? 
Are there parallel universes involved here or something?

Comment: That's not how time travel works in the Terminator universe. Things that traveled back don't *immediately* cease to exist just because the past is altered. That's how time travel works in Looper, where altering a person in the past also alters that same person after her has time traveled, but Looper physics don't apply to the Terminator franchise.

Comment: Ah, indeed! Looper and also Frequency!

Comment: Maybe an alternate timeline is created?

Comment: @RichS _Great Scott!_ It's that way in Looper too? _This is heavy_.

Comment: It's the difference between a time-line in closed loop and an open-ended time-line.

Answer (score 2):

As The Terminator itself says, there's still one chip in existence that could somehow make its way to the creation of Skynet and the Terminators: his own.

With such a large amount of time, there are many paths where that future could still happen.

Comment: Can you provide a source for your information? Or clarify a little exactly what you mean, I'm a little confused by the "one chip" and what it's supposed to represent.

Comment: Cyberdyn had been studying the CPU left behind by the destroyed T-800 in Terminator 1. The T-800 in Terminator 2 had the same kind of CPU. Cyberdyn could *theoretically* restart/recover its research if it could obtain that CPU again. So Arnold had to sacrifice himself to prevent that.

Comment: @Edlothiad: “his own”.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite sure, it represents Arnold's chip, but what is it's relevance beyond that?